# Xcode 6.3.2 manual build and sign gives error on installation: Application signature not valid

Tags: ios, xcode, sign, xcrun, xctool

When I´m running my automatic (command line) build, sign and upload script for my app, an error occurs when installing the app: 'Application signature not valid'.

It worked perfect for years before and stopped working 2 weeks ago (maybe due to Xcode update).

The same error occurs when I´m using HockeyApp for Mac OS to build the ipa and upload it.

When I´m doing the same manually in Xcode, then exporting it as .ipa, everything works well.

What could be the problem? I think xcodebuild is doing something different in the signing process than the manual Xcode .ipa-export.

My automatic build process (shortened)

```
xctool -workspace $WORKSPACE -scheme $SCHEME -configuration $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -sdk iphoneos clean archive
xcrun -log -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "$PRODUCT_PATH" -o $OUTPUTDIR/$APPNAME.ipa" -sign "$DEVELOPER_NAME" -embed "$PROVISIONING_PROFILE"
```

Comment: maybe the provisioning file and/or the developer id you're using aren't valid any more and Xcode is using a different one

Comment: Good hint, will check that definitely for my homegrown script! But HockeyApp for MacOS doesn´t need any provisioning profiles or developer id´s to build the ipa. So I´m assuming, it should use the same as Xcode...

Comment: did you try uploading a ipa that Xcode generate to hockeyapp using the web interface. If that works then Xcode is using one provisioning profile and the build script/hockey app are using different ones

Comment: The HockeyApp Mac app is *not* signing your app. It uses the app bundle from inside the xcarchive as it is.